# mysql is not connecting after data directory change

Tags: linux, mysql

I've changed data directory in /etc/my.cnf.

```
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I also moved mysql folder from

```
/var/lib/mysql/
```

to

```
/data/mysql
```

Now when i connect to mysql i get following error:

```
[root@youradstats-copy mysql]# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

also when i see /var/logs/msqld.log i get following messages in that:

```
InnoDB: Setting log file /data/mysql/ib_logfile0 size to 512 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Progress in MB: 100 200 300 400 500
120704  7:43:31  InnoDB: Log file /data/mysql/ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file /data/mysql/ib_logfile1 size to 512 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Progress in MB: 100 200 300 400 500
InnoDB: Cannot initialize created log files because
InnoDB: data files are corrupt, or new data files were
InnoDB: created when the database was started previous
InnoDB: time but the database was not shut down
InnoDB: normally after that.
120704  7:43:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120704  7:43:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

I shut down mysql properly before doing these changes and then started it properly but dont know why getting these messages. please help to solve issue as i have changed socket path in my.cnf but still its pointing to old path...

Comment: `ps -ef | grep mysql`?

Comment: Does MySQL has permissions to access /data/mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have the socket file in the new location?

ls -la /data/mysql/mysql.sock

If it exists, are the permissions correct?  Show us if you're unsure.

The next step if it exists is to try:

```
mysql -S /data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If that works then you simply need to change the `sock=/path/` in the `[client]` section of your `my.cnf` file.  If that doesn't exist there, then you should create it.

It is *not* required to restart mysql when you change things in the `[client]` section of the `my.cnf` file.

On another note, the log messages you posted makes it looks like you did not copy the data from your `/var/lib/mysql/` directory properly, or you have a permissions issue.  If you're unsure, show us the output of `ls -la /data/mysql/`

Answer (score 0):

You should have [mysql-client] section in your /etc/my.cnf or /root/.my.cnf file which define where the socket is located.

If you read your MySQL log, it tell you that restarting the database is required (/etc/init.d/mysqld restart).

Comment: i have this section in my.cnf file. also i restarted couple of times mysql after doing these changes but no success yet.